# Android Media player Repeat song For 'n' times and Timer value

Tags: android, timer, media-player, repeat

I would like to play the song for 'n' number of times as per the user input like 5,10 ..etc using android media player.

**For loop is not working as expected**
Please guide me how to achieve this.

I used the "onCompletion" but it is not working as expected but default repeat for infinite loop is working.

```
package com.example.vsr1.setitplayerversion2;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Timer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnCompletionListener, SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

    private ImageButton btnPlay;
    private ImageButton btnForward;
    private ImageButton btnBackward;
    private ImageButton btnNext;
    private ImageButton btnPrevious;
    private ImageButton btnPlaylist;
    private ImageButton btnRepeat;
    private ImageButton btnShuffle;
    private SeekBar songProgressBar;
    private TextView songTitleLabel;
    private TextView songCurrentDurationLabel;
    private TextView songTotalDurationLabel;
    private Dialog supportDialog;
    private RadioButton selectedBtn;
    private Context ctx;
    // Media Player
    private MediaPlayer mp;
    // Handler to update UI timer, progress bar etc,.
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();;
    private SongsManager songManager;
    private Utilities utils;
    private int seekForwardTime = 5000; // 5000 milliseconds
    private int seekBackwardTime = 5000; // 5000 milliseconds
    private int currentSongIndex = 0;
    private boolean isShuffle = false;
    private boolean isRepeat = false;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    private TextView songRepeatLabel;
    private TextView songRepeatCount;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.player);

        ctx = this;
        // All player buttons
        btnPlay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
        btnForward = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnForward);
        btnBackward = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnBackward);
        btnNext = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        btnPrevious = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPrevious);
        btnPlaylist = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPlaylist);
        btnRepeat = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnRepeat);
        btnShuffle = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnShuffle);
        songProgressBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.songProgressBar);
        songTitleLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songTitle);
        songCurrentDurationLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songCurrentDurationLabel);
        songTotalDurationLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songTotalDurationLabel);
        songRepeatLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtRepeatLabel);
         songRepeatCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtRepeatCount);
        // Mediaplayer
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
        songManager = new SongsManager();
        utils = new Utilities();

        // Listeners
        songProgressBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this); // Important
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(this); // Important
        mp.setLooping(false);

        // Getting all songs list
        songsList = songManager.getPlayList(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());

        //Button showDialog = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sh)

        // By default play first song
       //if(songsList!=null && songsList.size()>0) playSong(0);

        /**
         * Play button click event
         * plays a song and changes button to pause image
         * pauses a song and changes button to play image
         * */
        btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // check for already playing
                if(mp.isPlaying()){
                    if(mp!=null){
                        mp.pause();
                        // Changing button image to play button
                        btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_play);
                    }
                }else{
                    // Resume song
                    if(mp!=null){
                        mp.start();
                        // Changing button image to pause button
                        btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause);
                    }
                }

            }
        });

        /**
         * Forward button click event
         * Forwards song specified seconds
         * */
        btnForward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // get current song position
                int currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
                // check if seekForward time is lesser than song duration
                if(currentPosition + seekForwardTime <= mp.getDuration()){
                    // forward song
                    mp.seekTo(currentPosition + seekForwardTime);
                }else{
                    // forward to end position
                    mp.seekTo(mp.getDuration());
                }
            }
        });

        /**
         * Backward button click event
         * Backward song to specified seconds
         * */
        btnBackward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // get current song position
                int currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
                // check if seekBackward time is greater than 0 sec
                if(currentPosition - seekBackwardTime >= 0){
                    // forward song
                    mp.seekTo(currentPosition - seekBackwardTime);
                }else{
                    // backward to starting position
                    mp.seekTo(0);
                }

            }
        });

        /**
         * Next button click event
         * Plays next song by taking currentSongIndex + 1
         * */
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // check if next song is there or not
                if(currentSongIndex < (songsList.size() - 1)){
                    playSong(currentSongIndex + 1);
                    currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex + 1;
                }else{
                    // play first song
                    playSong(0);
                    currentSongIndex = 0;
                }

            }
        });

        /**
         * Back button click event
         * Plays previous song by currentSongIndex - 1
         * */
        btnPrevious.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if(currentSongIndex > 0){
                    playSong(currentSongIndex - 1);
                    currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex - 1;
                }else{
                    // play last song
                    playSong(songsList.size() - 1);
                    currentSongIndex = songsList.size() - 1;
                }

            }
        });

        /**
         * Button Click event for Repeat button
         * Enables repeat flag to true
         * */
        btnRepeat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if(isRepeat){
                    isRepeat = false;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Repeat is OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    btnRepeat.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_repeat);
                }else{
                    // make repeat to true
                    isRepeat = true;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Repeat is ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    showDialog(); // call popup
                    songRepeatCount.setText(String.valueOf(initialRepeatCount));
                    // make shuffle to false
                    isShuffle = false;
                    btnRepeat.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_repeat_focused);
                    btnShuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_shuffle);
                }
            }
        });

        /**
         * Button Click event for Shuffle button
         * Enables shuffle flag to true
         * */
        btnShuffle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if(isShuffle){
                    isShuffle = false;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Shuffle is OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    btnShuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_shuffle);
                }else{
                    // make repeat to true
                    isShuffle= true;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Shuffle is ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // make shuffle to false
                    isRepeat = false;
                    btnShuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_shuffle_focused);
                    btnRepeat.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_repeat);
                }
            }
        });

        /**
         * Button Click event for Play list click event
         * Launches list activity which displays list of songs
         * */
        btnPlaylist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PlayListActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(i, 100);
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Receiving song index from playlist view
     * and play the song
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,
                                    int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode == 100){
            currentSongIndex = data.getExtras().getInt("songIndex");
            // play selected song
            playSong(currentSongIndex);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Function to play a song
     * @param songIndex - index of song
     * */
    public void  playSong(int songIndex){
        // Play song
        try {
            if(songsList!=null && songsList.size()>0) {
                mp.reset();
                mp.setDataSource(songsList.get(songIndex).get("songPath"));
                mp.prepare();
                mp.start();
                // Displaying Song title
                String songTitle = songsList.get(songIndex).get("songTitle");
                songTitleLabel.setText(songTitle);

                // Changing Button Image to pause image
                btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause);

                // set Progress bar values
                songProgressBar.setProgress(0);
                songProgressBar.setMax(100);

                // Updating progress bar
                updateProgressBar();
            }
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Update timer on seekbar
     * */
    public void updateProgressBar() {
        mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);
    }

    /**
     * Background Runnable thread
     * */
    private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            long totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
            long currentDuration = mp.getCurrentPosition();

            // Displaying Total Duration time
            songTotalDurationLabel.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(totalDuration));
            // Displaying time completed playing
            songCurrentDurationLabel.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration));

            // Updating progress bar
            int progress = (int)(utils.getProgressPercentage(currentDuration, totalDuration));
            //Log.d("Progress", ""+progress);
            songProgressBar.setProgress(progress);

            // Running this thread after 100 milliseconds
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
        }
    };

    /**
     *
     * */
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromTouch) {

    }

    /**
     * When user starts moving the progress handler
     * */
    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // remove message Handler from updating progress bar
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
    }

    /**
     * When user stops moving the progress hanlder
     * */
    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
        int totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
        int currentPosition = utils.progressToTimer(seekBar.getProgress(), totalDuration);

        // forward or backward to certain seconds
        mp.seekTo(currentPosition);

        // update timer progress again
        updateProgressBar();
    }

    private int initialRepeatCount;
    private Timer initialRepeatTimerValue;
    /**
     * On Song Playing completed
     * if repeat is ON play same song again
     * if shuffle is ON play random song
     * */
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {

        int count = 0;
        // check for repeat is ON or OFF
        if(isRepeat)
        {
            if(initialRepeatCount>0)
            {
                // initial Repeat song
                count=initialRepeatCount;
                for (int i=count;i>=1; i--){
                    songRepeatCount.setText(String.valueOf(count));
                    playSong(currentSongIndex);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Repeat ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    count=i;
                }
                // Next song repeat same count
                if(songsList!=null && currentSongIndex < (songsList.size() - 1)){
                    currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex + 1;

                    count=initialRepeatCount;
                    for (int i=count;i>=1; i--){
                        playSong(currentSongIndex);
                        count=i;
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Next song Repeat ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        songRepeatCount.setText(String.valueOf(count));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // play first song
                    playSong(0);
                    currentSongIndex = 0;
                    count=initialRepeatCount;

                    for (int i=count;i>=1; i--){
                        playSong(currentSongIndex);
                        count=i;
                        songRepeatCount.setText(String.valueOf(count));
                    }
                }
            }
            // inital Timer value
           /* else if (Timer.value)
            {

            }*/
            // default Repeat
            else
            {   // repeat is on play same song again
                playSong(currentSongIndex);
            }
        }

        else if(isShuffle)
        {
            // shuffle is on - play a random song
            Random rand = new Random();
            currentSongIndex = rand.nextInt((songsList.size() - 1) - 0 + 1) + 0;
            playSong(currentSongIndex);
        } else
        {
            // no repeat or shuffle ON - play next song
            if(songsList!=null && currentSongIndex < (songsList.size() - 1))
            {
                playSong(currentSongIndex + 1);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Default next song ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex + 1;
            }else
            {
                // play first song
                playSong(0);
                currentSongIndex = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        mp.release();
    }


    public void showDialog(){
        supportDialog = new Dialog(ctx,android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar);

        supportDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        supportDialog.setContentView(R.layout.user_input_fragment); // add your custom layout pop up
        supportDialog.setCancelable(true);
        supportDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true); // if it is set false if you touch outside of the popup ,popup will not close.
        supportDialog.setTitle("Set Repeat");


        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        Window window = supportDialog.getWindow();
        lp.copyFrom(window.getAttributes());
        //This makes the dialog take up the full width
        lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT; // it will take respective mobile screen hight and width
        lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;

        window.setAttributes(lp);
        //supportDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT)); // enable to set color transparant

        final RadioGroup rgrp;
        final EditText txt2;
        final TimePicker tp;
        // TextView txtRepeatValue;
         //TextView txtRepeatLabel;
        Button ok;
        Button cancel;

        rgrp = (RadioGroup)supportDialog.findViewById(R.id.rgrp);
        txt2 = (EditText)supportDialog.findViewById(R.id.txt2);
        tp = (TimePicker)supportDialog.findViewById(R.id.txt3);
        ok = (Button)supportDialog.findViewById(R.id.ok_btn);
        cancel =(Button)supportDialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel_btn);

        tp.setIs24HourView(true);
        txt2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        tp.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        rgrp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                int id = rgrp.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

                View radioButton = rgrp.findViewById(id);

                // Check which radio button was clicked
                switch (radioButton.getId()) {
                    case R.id.rb1:
                        txt2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        tp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        break;
                    case R.id.rb2:
                        txt2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        tp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        txt2.setFocusable(true);
                        txt2.setCursorVisible(true);
                        break;
                    case R.id.rb3:
                        tp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        txt2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        tp.setFocusable(true);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        supportDialog.show();

        ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int id = rgrp.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

                View radioButton = rgrp.findViewById(id);

                // Check which radio button was clicked
                switch (radioButton.getId()) {
                    case R.id.rb1:
                        Toast.makeText(ctx, "default selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        supportDialog.dismiss();
                        break;
                    case R.id.rb2:
                        Toast.makeText(ctx, "set count edit text value " + txt2.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        initialRepeatCount = Integer.parseInt(txt2.getText().toString());
                        songRepeatLabel.setText("Repeat :");
                        songRepeatCount.setText(txt2.getText());
                        supportDialog.dismiss();
                        break;
                    case R.id.rb3:
                        String strDateTime = tp.getCurrentHour() + " : " + tp.getCurrentMinute();
                        Toast.makeText(ctx, "Timer selected " + strDateTime, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        supportDialog.dismiss();
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                supportDialog.cancel();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try the following `mp.setLooping(false);`.

> Edits

Please set on complete listener on Media player object like

mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);

You can achieve your requirement following way.

You can set the mp.setLooping(false).set the counter to increase by 1 `onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer)` method and check

```
  if(count==total){
        //create method to change the song
        changetheSongorreleaseMediaplayer();
        }  
    else{
      //create method to replay the song
       replaythesamesong();
     }
```